# Fix CSS to add icon to Elementor Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, icons, elementor

I uploaded icons to my menu using class and css code (Wordpress + Elementor), but I can't remove the space between the icon and the text.
Used the following code example:

```
    .frio 
{
background-image: url('https://zine.unlatino.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/icon_frio.svg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left;
background-size: 30px;
padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Maybe I'm missing correctly modifying the code so that the text follows after the icon.
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```html
try adding to your class css

margin-left:5px; // based on ur preference
if that dosen't work u can try the following  

position:relative;
left:5px; // based on ur preference

altghought i recommend you try to find what's going on using the development tool
```

Comment: Sorry, but none of that has worked.

Comment: Some css could be overriding  the properties you just added try to enforce them by adding space followed by !important next to each property you just added

Comment: Nothing has happened. This is my current css code with the data that has been mentioned to me, for the first icon (Snow).

.frio {
background-image: url('https://zine.unlatino.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/icon_frio.svg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left;
background-size: 30px;
padding-left: 5px;
margin-left:5px!important;
position:relative!important;
}

Comment: hi, could you please try this .fio{    background-image: url(https://zine.unlatino.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/icon_frio.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    background-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 47px;
    position: relative !important;
    left: 10px !important; } as written the number of pixels on the left should be based on your need

Comment: See for yourself: zine.unlatino.com
 The icon has disappeared.
Any other solution? Perhaps loading the image directly into the Menu section, without CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best solution, but removed the CSS and added

```
<img src="https://zine.unlatino.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/icon_frio.svg" width="32" height = "32" />
```

in front of the text and aligned as expected.
If there is any other solution feel free to comment.